# Div animate disappears, rather than resizing

Tags: javascript

For some reason, when I try to toggle a div between two sizes using .animate, it simply disappears rather than scaling to the size I want it to.  I have played with all of the the syntax and little things in so many ways, but nothing works. Here is the jquery that I have used and messed around with a bunch.

```
$("#expandable").click(
    function() {
        $("#expandable").toggle(
            function() {
                $("#expandable").animate(
                    {width:600, height:600}
                )
            },
            function() {
                $("#expandable").animate(
                    {width:400, height:200}
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I have a jsfiddle here for you to look at.
http://jsfiddle.net/justinbc820/qt7GV/

Comment: `toggle` will `show / hide` a div

Comment: with new jquery toggle behaves differently than it was earlier. So try with normal click listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it without using toggle

**http://jsfiddle.net/qt7GV/9/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#expandable").click(function(){
      var divheight = $(this).height();
      if (divheight == 400)
      {
          $(this).animate({height:'150px', width:'150px' });
      }
      else
      {
          $(this).animate({height:'400px', width:'400px' });
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: this is not a toggle. this will perform both actions each click.

Comment: @zzlalani please check again

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

> Description: Display or hide the matched elements.

```
var on = false;
var box = $("#expandable");
box.click(
    function() {

        if (on = !on) { 
            box.animate(
                    {width:600, height:600}
                )
        } else {
            box.animate(
                    {width:400, height:200}
                );
        }            

    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

> Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6rR3A/) is one way to do it

```
$('#expandable').data('flag', true);
$("#expandable").click(
  function() { 
    $("#expandable").animate(
        $(this).data('flag') 
        ? {width:600, height:600}
        : {width:400, height:200}
    )
    $(this).data('flag', !$(this).data('flag'));
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/qt7GV/4/

```
$("#expandable").click(function() {

    if ($(this).width() < 600) {
         $(this).animate(
             {width:600, height:600}
         )
    } else {
        $(this).animate(
            {width:400, height:200}
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: @zzalalani I don't know who gave you -1, but I give you +1 because you gave the correct answer